# Error when trying to load external js file in index.html (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I'm getting the following error when I try to load an external js file in the index.html

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This how I'm calling it:

```
<script async src="/src/assets/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure why it's giving this error because if I use cdnjs it works fine:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

I can provide more details if necessary.

Comment: It looks like the path is wrong and your server is serving HTML instead (like a 404 error page).

Comment: What does it say in your browser's address bar?

Comment: Try to use this this link `https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric` then install it using `Vue.use(fabric)`

Comment: @ChrisG If you're asking about the url, I'm running on localhost: `http://localhost:8080/#/`

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen when I try installing it on npm, there's some errors, so I'm sticking with the safer route.

Comment: @ChrisG ah I read around it a bit more, seems like files that index.html need to depend on need to be in the `static` folder

Comment: @A.Lau Right, so what do you see when you go to http://localhost:8080/src/assets/fabric.min.js ?

Comment: @ChrisG Can't seem to access it, it just returns me to the homepage, since I'm using a router.

Comment: @A.Lau Exactly, the server sends back the index file, which starts with `<`. But you already solved it.

Comment: @ChrisG yeah, your tip that it wasn't returning the right file helped me out, thx

Comment: I am having the same issue too . So if I need to load scripts which are not configured with vue-loader or the config under webpack ,but need to run the app with webpack and vueload, what is the right way to go about it?

Comment: @SainathS.R If I think you're having the same problem, you need to move the files into the `static` folder, then access it via `www.example.com/static/filename.js` or maybe simply just `static/filename.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by moving the required file into the `static` folder.